# osm2pgsql: Extracting full buildings polygons + addresses text from OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I'm trying to extract all the polygons for the buildings in my country, however, it seems osm2pgsql is extracting very little information compared to what I need.

My idea was that I will rely on the empty.style file and I've set everything to have the "delete" flag, and keep only the tag=[building=yes], importing the building footprints should work. A brief extract from the style file:

```
# OsmType   Tag                     Type    Flags
# Insert your own columns here, or change polygon,nocolumn to polygon below
....
node,way    amenity                 text    delete
node,way    building=yes            text    polygon,nocolumn
....
```

The problem with this is I am seeing more unwanted polygons (administrative delimitation in Luxembourg) and less of the needed polygons (all the "mapped" buildings footprint polygons).

This is how my file looks like atm: http://pastebin.com/hwtYth22

This is how things look where the tag building=yes, notice the administrative areas polygons making it into the database, but also the lack of all the known polygons:

[image: luxembourg central]

If I revert from "building=yes", and I leave it only "building", I get more polygons, but still, not all the buildings, yet more compared to using the "building=yes" tag.

Any advice on what I can do to:

- prevent the administrative boundaries from showing up in postgres
- have all the building footprints in postgres so I can filter them out by Office/amenity/etc.

TY,
Mark

Comment: Can you tell me where this map came from? ( geo coordinates ) so I can investigate the elements in OSM website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/building#values, the `building` tag is not limited to `yes`, but several others. Try to use like `default.style` :

`node,way   building     text         polygon`

I don't know why you're using `nocolumn`.

The administrative boundaries came from ( http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/admin_level )

`node,way   admin_level  text         linear`.

Make sure you're not importing it.

Also try to include `amenity` since it have a combination with `building`: http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/amenity#combinations

At last, play a little here before do the import: http://overpass-turbo.eu/

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback Magno. Wouldn't the `amenity` tag come with a `building` tag by default in OSM?

Comment: `building` can have an amenity `value`. There is an `amenity` tag too with its own values. The tags are known by `Keys`wich become columns in the `planet_osm_*` tables. So, `building=amenity` will select just buildings wich have an amenity value ( something like `select * from planet_osm_polygon where building = 'amenity' `).

Answer (score 0):

This may be irrelevant, but have you tried imposm 3 or osmosis? They may provide different results.

Comment: I am extracting the data from PBF to postgres directly.

I tried imposm but it halts during the import.

Played with osmosis and the filter feature is not as flexible as osm2pgsql. Had to abandon osmosis for that reason. 

Both osmosis and osm2pgsql give the same results, but osm2pgsql seems to be more practical at "filtering out" the entities from the PBF file, as I am looking at an easy to maintain solution.